# What is the best one to be used? Today is Sunday or It's Sunday today.?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

What is the best one to be used?
What ones are 100% correct?

Today is Sunday or It's Sunday today?

Is that correct too -> "Today it's Sunday"?

And one more question, What about these: "Today is so cold", "It's so cold today"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: All three are just different ways of saying the same thing. None is 'better' or 'more correct'.

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks for info.